# Add class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this has been asked many times before, but I could not find anything that worked. 
I will need to add a class to a div that gets autogenerated over my ul.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="bx-pager">
       <li><a><img></a></li>
       <li><a><img></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to add a second class to div class "wrapper", but after what I have tried I can't get it to work. I would be nice if someone can help me out with this simple task, but showing me how to do it. I don't have much experience with jQuery, but need it now.

Comment: Please post full code to better understand

Comment: Well this is used with bxSlider, and when it automatic puts the UL list inside of a div class"bx-viewport", but I need to add a second class to bx-viewport, to change the css.

Comment: `$('wrapper').addClass('newClass');` if you don't put your code how can we help you!!! how can we know which element/object you have??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the JQuery [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector:

```
$('#bx-pager').parent('div').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 5):

In pure javaScript

```
this.parentElement.classList.add('newClass');
```

**Updated**

```js
const myElement = document.querySelector('#bx-pager');
myElement.parentElement.classList.add('new-class');
```

```css
.new-class {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="bx-pager">
    <li>
      <a><img></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a><img></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple find parent and add new class. You can use following code to find any parent and add new class.

```
$(this).parent().addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that you are new to query: [here](http://jsbin.com/eRALEXo/1/edit?html,js,output) is the link to the working example.