# Manipulating parent div elment on basis of its child div elment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to add any style property like 'float' to the `parent div` element on the basis of its `child div` element(preferably using javascript and without adding any extra div).

```
<div class="chat-message">
    <span class="chat-message-me">xxx</span>
    <span class="chat-message-content">hiyyy</span>
</div>

<div class="chat-message">
    <span class="chat-message-them">01:25 me:&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="chat-message-content">hi</span>
</div>
```

like in this code sample the parent divs are same but the child divs differ in class. So can we float the div element on its basis?

i suppose it would require the 'if' statement but i am unable to do it..

please help.

Thanx!

Comment: This would not be possible in CSS alone. Please add the code you've written yourself to the question.

Comment: Why don't you add the desired class to parent div directly in HTML instead of adding it after loading DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery:

```
$('chat-message-them').parent().addClass('left');
```

CSS

```
.left {float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $('.chat-message-me').parent('div').addClass('newClass');
```

[Have a Look](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539906/add-class-to-parent-element)

Answer (score 0):

If you used sass, this is easily possible. For example this bit of css (in a sass sheet) will target the parent directories:

```
.chat-message-me { 
  .chat-message & {
    float: left;
  }
}
.chat-message-from { 
  .chat-message & {
    float: right;
  }
}
```